# Prolog - Towers Of Hanoi, outputting the "towers" as they are after each step

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, towers-of-hanoi

I have seen multiple questions showing the way how one could solve the Towers Of Hanoi question in Prolog with and without lists, however what I haven't seen yet is a way for one to use the recursive algorithm, while also being able to output each step.

Here is my code of the Hanoi algorithm:

```
move(1,[H|T],B,C,Origin,Dummy,Destination) :-  
            Origin = T,
            Destination = [H|C],
            Dummy = B.

move(Disks,Start1,Auxiliary1,End1,Sf,Af,Ef) :-   
            Disks>1, 
            M is Disks-1,
            move(M,Start1,End1,Auxiliary1,S1,E1,A1),
            printHanoi(S1,A1,E1),
            move(1,S1,A1,E1,S2,A2,E2),
            printHanoi(S2,A2,E2),
            move(M,A2,S2,E2,Af,Sf,Ef),
            printHanoi(Sf,Af,Ef).

printHanoi(Left,Centre,Right):-
    write('L = '), write(Left),
    write(' C = '), write(Centre),
    write(' R = '), write(Right), nl.
```

With a list of size 3 ( [1,2,3] ), this is what the output comes out to:

```
L = [2,3] C = [1] R = []
L = [3] C = [1] R = [2]
L = [3] C = [] R = [1,2]
L = [3] C = [1,2] R = []
L = [] C = [1,2] R = [3]
L = [2] C = [1] R = [3]
L = [] C = [1] R = [2,3]
L = [] C = [] R = [1,2,3]
L = [] C = [] R = [1,2,3]
L = [] C = [] R = [1,2,3]
yes
```

Ignoring the original output (meaning with L being [1,2,3]), and those last 3 repeated listings (not so important), the output seems to be having problems.

In a lot of lines, Lists seem to be being swapped with each other. My preferred/expected output here would be like so:

```
L = [2,3] C = [] R = [1]
L = [3] C = [2] R = [1]
L = [3] C = [1,2] R = []
L = [] C = [1,2] R = [3]
L = [1] C = [2] R = [3]
L = [1] C = [] R = [2,3]
L = [] C = [] R = [1,2,3]
yes
```

I'm not sure whether this is even possible or not, I'm hoping that it is, but I'll take all the help I can get at this point, because I cannot find a single logical way how I could output the correct order of steps of the Towers Of Hanoi problem...

Comment: Depending on what you mean by intermediate steps...

Comment: For that, I'm assuming that R and C are swapped. The output should be `L = [3] C = [2] R = [1]` and `L = [3] C =[1,2] R = []`.

Comment: Oh wait, now I get what you mean. Nono, in this question it's possible to move from the leftmost to the rightmost in a single step. You're not forced to only move over one tower at a time.

Comment: you should have only one `printHanoi` call inside your `move` predicate.

Comment: If I do that then half of the steps aren't even shown.

Comment: they are not steps. each step is done in the base case only, which is the middle call to `move(1,...`. The other two are recursive calls that - each - will eventually get to doing the `move(1,...` themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to solve as you ask is actually to add extra arguments... very carefully.

The code is here: https://gist.github.com/fidelcoria/9a38309c82fbc829ae23f9f94a24aee6

The extra arguments keep track of which peg the each corresponding list is. I represent pegs as atoms `a`,`b`, and `c`. When it comes to printing I use an if-else-if structure to choose which to print first (X,Y, or Z; see the code), which second and which last.